# KVO firing when value assigned is not different

Tags: ios, cocoa, key-value-observing

If I have a property as follows

```
@property(assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger myValue;
```

And assign a property to it

```
self.myValue = 2;
```

KVO will fire as expected. If, later on, I then assign the same value to it

```
self.myValue = 2;
```

KVO will fire again. I had presumed that KVO in Objective-C would not fire if the value being assigned was not different. It appears that I am incorrect.

Is there a way to force this default behaviour, i.e. disable the KVO notifications firing every time a value is assigned? I can create my own accessors, but this could be quite a lot of work if there are a lot of properties that I want to change...

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: If it is important for some reason that a particular notification is only fired when when the value changes, then you either need to write a custom setter or check the value before setting it.  ie `if (self.myValue != 2) self.myValue = 2`.

Comment: A great question, and it's surprising this is never made really clear in the Apple doco.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

KVO fires when a setter (or other mutator) is called. There is no additional check. In general, KVO is extremely lightweight and performance sensitive. Since unnecessary changes are typically rare and in most cases harmless to the observer, they do not include the extra overhead of checking the old value. Checking the previous value could be expensive, for instance if a managed object hadn't been faulted, so doing a lot of work just to check for this case is not a default behavior.

If you need to check how the value changed or didn't, you can do so as the observer by passing the options `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld`. You will then receive both the new and old values and you can decide whether to do anything with that information. I've found in practice that this shouldn't be needed very often, however.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld values already to get around this. It's no big deal, I was just wondering if there was an easier and 'built in' way to do this. Cheers!

Comment: I had exactly the same thoughts, Niall.  It's good to hear confirmation from Rob that, indeed, the system DOES send a message, even if the value it just set is the same.  Thought, in some cases, and here I mean purely for performance (in the rare cases that matters) it may be better to check on the "sending end" that it is an unchanged value (and hence, simply don't set it) rather than checking on the "receiving end" (for example, if you have very many of receivers and you're making a complicated comparison, a string or whatever).  Thanks again Rob Napier.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, to add this logic to the setter (using manual change notification) you would use:

```
- (void)setValue:(int)value
{
    if (_value == value) return;
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"value"];
    _value = value;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"value"];
}

+ (BOOL)automaticallyNotifiesObserversOfValue { return NO; }
```

Comment: This is what I do! It's documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-SW1

Comment: This is what I do, too. Better for performance and maintainability than repeating checks across a potentially large number of receivers.